# Выборка в случайном порядке отсутствующих значений из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: mysql

Привет всем.
Есть две таблицы A и B.

```
=======A========
id  people_id
1   77
2   3
3   45
4   77
6   3
================
```

изначально таблица B пустая, структура такова

```
======B=======
id  people_id
==============
```

Есть необходимость выбрать значения из таблицы A в случайном порядке, с установленным лимитом, так чтобы в таблице B записей идентичных записей не было. Проверка уникальности необходима по полю people_id.

Попробовал запрос такого вида:

```
SELECT
    c.people_id
FROM
    lt_codes c
WHERE
    c.people_id
NOT IN
    (SELECT w.people_id FROM lt_winners w)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT $selectCount
```

После уникальной выборки, значения сохраняются (с этим разобрался) из таблицы A в таблицу B, затем операция выборки уникальности повторяется по инициативе пользователя.
Могли бы помочь советом те кто хорошо разбирается в этом деле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше JOIN и isnull использовать чтобы находить отсутствующие значения:

```
INSERT INTO B (
               SELECT NULL,A.people_id from A LEFT JOIN B ON B.people_id=A.people_id 
       WHERE ISNULL(B.people_id) 
       GROUP BY A.people_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8df7a/1