# Помогите составить запрос с условиями по отношению к нескольким таблицам

Tags: mysql

A - 
Таблица представляет собою таблицу вероятности;
Где записи о пользователе могут повторяться,
и должны выбираться посредством ORDER BY RAND();

```
-----------------------
id  name    people_id
1   Joe     1
2   Joe     1
3   Slim    4
4   Chris   7
5   Chris   7
6   Ford    8
7   Mikey   22
-----------------------
```

B - база с призами

поле uni определяет:
0 - приз могут получить только те, кто ещё не получал приз;
1 - приз получают даже те, кто уже получил другие призы;

```
------------------------
id  name    uni
1   Приз-1  0
2   Приз-2  0
3   Приз-3  0
3   Приз-3  1
3   Приз-3  1
------------------------
```

C - таблица с результатами

```
----------------------------------
id  people_id   present_id
----------------------------------
1   7           1
2   7           2
```

Есть необходимость выбрать случайных пользователей из таблицы A
при условии что в таблице C нет записей с present_id == id (таблица B) со значением uni=1,
но при этом допускается чтобы present_id == id со значением uni=0

До этого спрашивал на эту тему:
[ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/286379/mysql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E)

Однако задача поменялась немного иначе.
Нужна помощь в составлении запроса, запутался окончательно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Держите](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdb702/4/3).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо!
Решил так:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT C.people_id AS id,
    P.name,
    P.code,
    P.city
FROM
    lt_codes C
LEFT JOIN lt_peoples P ON (C.people_id = P.id)
LEFT JOIN lt_winners W ON(
        C.people_id = W.people_id
    AND
        W.present_id IN ((SELECT PR.id FROM lt_presents PR WHERE un_peoples=0))
        )
    WHERE W.present_id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT $selectCount
```

Comment: Зачем "DISTINCT"? При его использовании теряется весь смысл в таблице вероятностей "А".